# Bash - invalid arithmetic operator

Tags: bash

I'm trying to study for a test and one of the subjects are bash scripts.
I have the following txt file :

```
123456 100 
654321 50 
203374111 86
```

I need to get the averages of the scores (the numbers in the second column).

This is what I have written :

```
cat $course_name$end | while read line; do
    sum=`echo $line | cut -f2 -d" "`
    let total+=$sum
done
```

I have tried with

> while read -a line

and then

> let sum+=${line[1]}

But I'm still getting the same error mentioned in the header.

Comment: No need for `cut`; `read` can handle the word splitting for you with `with read id sum; do let total+=sum; done`. `id` is just a placeholder for whatever the first column is.

Answer (score 1):

I love AWK:

```
awk -F\* '{sum+=$3} END {print sum/NR}' x.txt
```

So in x.txt are values are stored. Please note that many answers don't actually compute the average, as they need to divide by the line numbers in the end. Often it will be performed by a `wc -l < x.txt` but in my solution you will get it almost for free.

Comment: I have to say that I like the solution, but note that the OP says that `I'm trying to study for a test and one of the subjects are bash scripts`, so we can guess that is basically looking for a pure bash solution. By the way, I also love `awk`, it is such a powerful language!

Comment: I think that it should be `sum+=$2` and there's no need to change the input separator - it looks like the OP was trying to make the numbers bold using `**number**` but it doesn't work in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, this works for me:

```
while read line; do
    sum=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d" ")
    echo "sum is $sum"
    let total+=$sum
    echo "total is $total"
done < file

echo "total is $total"
```

As you can see, there is no need to use `cat $course_name$end`, it is enough to do

```
while read line
do

done < file
```

Also, it is more recommendable to use

```
sum=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d" ")
```

rather than

```
sum=`echo $line | cut -f2 -d" "`
```

Or even

```
sum=$(cut -f2 -d" " <<< "$line")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat your_file_name.txt | cut -f2 -d" " | paste -sd+ | bc
```

This should do the job!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `cat` as well as `read`; you can redirect the contents of the file into the loop. You also don't need to use `let` for arithmetic.

```
sum = 0
count = 0
while read id score; do
    (( sum += score )) && (( ++count ))
done < "$course_name$end"

echo $(( sum / count ))
```

This will give you an integer result, as bash doesn't do floating point arithmetic. To get a floating point result, you could use `bc`:

```
bc <<< "scale=2;$a/$b"
```

This will give you a result correct to 2 decimal places.